# Moving unique_ptrs from one vector to another

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I'd like to move the unique_ptr's stored in an unsorted vector of them to another vector, that will contain the sorted vector of pointers.

Surely moving a unique_ptr will not automatically erase the element in the first vector? How can I do this?

Example of what I want to do:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > unsorted, sorted;
// fill the "unsorted" vector
while( unsorted.size() > 0 )
{
    const auto it = find_next_element_to_add_to_sorted(unsorted);
    sorted.push_back( std::move(*it) );
}
```

I hope the intent is clear.

**UPDATE**: [my algorithm](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/08/07/dependency-resolving-algorithm/) does not allow sorting in-place. If anyone is feeling nice today (I am not asking, see above for my question), feel free to implement it for this situation and show me. I really need the "sort by move". And I don't really see why the moving would be *that* much more expensive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your code looks basically correct to me, except that it *seems* like you intend for the moved-from `unique_ptr` to be erased from the unsorted vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > unsorted, sorted;
// fill the "unsorted" vector
while( unsorted.size() > 0 )
{
    const auto it = find_next_element_to_add_to_sorted(unsorted);
    sorted.push_back( std::move(*it) );
    unsorted.erase(it);
}
```

After the move `it` refers to a moved-from `unique_ptr` and `*it == nullptr`.  It still exists in `unsorted` and if that is not desired, must be explicitly erased.

Comment: Thanks! What is the "content" of `it` after the `move`? You solution seems nice and clean, and exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm confused about `it` after the `move` operation. (completely offtopic: can't wait for libc++ to be functional on Windows!)

Comment: It appeared to me that `it` is an iterator into vector because of the way you are using it.  If so, `it` refers to a unique_ptr.  After the move, that unique_ptr will be equal to nullptr.

Comment: Yes, ok. I didn't know about that.

Comment: This appears like it would do the trick, although the algorithm outlined in the OP code doesn't seem the same as the algorithm in the linked article.

Comment: Mark B: I didn't write the algorithm here, as it is irrelevant for what I'm trying to do here. The example code I gave would be part of the algorithm (in the link's last code block, the `push_back` and `erase` in this answer would replace the last two lines (the `append` and `remove` calls))

Comment: The template >[space]> is no longer needed in C++0x by the way

Comment: @David: I know, "bad" habit I guess.